# int android.widget.TextView.getVisibility()' on a null object reference

Tags: android, android-fragments

> Blockquote

I want to blink `TextView` inside `Fragment` but this was giving an error reference null object here is my code. I am new to android please any one can help really appreciate it very much

```
public class TwoFragment extends Fragment {
    View inflaterView;

    public TwoFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        inflaterView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);

        blink();
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflaterView;
    }


    private void blink() {
        final Handler handler = new Handler();

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                int timeToBlink = 1000;
                //in milissegunds
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(timeToBlink);

                } catch (Exception e) {

                }

                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        TextView txt = (TextView) inflaterView.findViewById(R.id.usage);

                        if (txt.getVisibility() == inflaterView.VISIBLE) {
                            txt.setVisibility(inflaterView.INVISIBLE);

                        } else {
                            txt.setVisibility(inflaterView.VISIBLE);

                        }

                        blink();
                    }
                });
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

> here is the error

```
04-01 22:25:34.471  27846-27846/com.example.siluni.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.siluni.myapplication, PID: 27846
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.widget.TextView.getVisibility()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.siluni.myapplication.TwoFragment$1$1.run(TwoFragment.java:59)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5930)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1405)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1200)
```

> Xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="info.androidhive.materialtabs.fragments.OneFragment">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/usage"
    android:layout_marginTop="220dip"
    android:layout_marginLeft="45dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dip"
    android:typeface="serif"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Google "
    android:textColor="#030900"/>
```

Comment: Can you post the full error message?

Comment: Did you contain a TextView with id (@+id/usage) in R.layout.fragment_one?

Comment: yp there is text view from that id

Comment: I have edit the question with error i am getting

Comment: Why do you have a Runnable within a Handler within a Runnable within a Thread?

Comment: Do you have a `R.layout.fragment_two`? You named your class TwoFragment, but the XML says `OneFragment`

Comment: yp .ypu are correct It was wrong there.Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am getting the toggling ,change your layout according to your need.
My Fragment

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
TextView txt;
View inflaterView;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    inflaterView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.de, container, false);
    txt= (TextView) inflaterView.findViewById(R.id.type);
    blink();
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflaterView;
}


private void blink() {
    final Handler handler = new Handler();

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            int timeToBlink = 1000;
            //in milissegunds
            try {
                Thread.sleep(timeToBlink);

            } catch (Exception e) {

            }

            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {


                    if (txt.isShown() ) {
                        txt.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                    } else {
                        txt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    }

                    blink();
                }
            });
        }
    }).start();
}
```

My Xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/type"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight=".5"
        android:text="jekjkejd"
        android:textStyle="bold"

        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"

        />


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: txt.getVisibility() was underlined as a error showing required boolean found int

Comment: instead of the txt.getVisibility() put txt.isShown()

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.widget.TextView.isShown()' on a null object reference

Comment: can you attach xml ?

Comment: above i updated the code check it ,i am getting the toggling

Comment: I have tried now this is working .Thank you very much .appreciate your answer

Answer (score 0):

If you have textinputlayout without any edittext or autocompleteTextview inside it, than it will throw null pointer exception.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

//Put some textview here

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```